# Cent OS 8 relocation error after installing Openssl

Tags: openssl, centos

I download and install `openssl 1.1.1` following this [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/) on my CentOS 8 server. But after that I cannot run commands like `yum`,`rpm`,`ssh`. For example:

```
ssh: /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1b' not found (required by ssh)

rpm: relocation error: /lib64/librpmio.so.8: symbol EVP_md2 version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference
```

Comment: CentOS 8 already has OpenSSL 1.1.1, so what you did makes little to no sense. This forum is for programming questions.

Comment: I'm having similar issues because I installed python 3.9 which requires an updated version of openssl (newer than the default c that comes with c8)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a line /usr/lib in the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf file
2. Save
3. Run the ldconfig command

Reference link:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11227

Answer (score 0):

you can give this a go

`curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -`

`sudo yum install nodejs`

solved my issue, running centOS and aaPanel